# Parameterized array of Interface SystemVerilog

Tags: parameters, interface, system-verilog

Im trying to create a parameterized array of interface instances in SystemVerilog, but somehow fail to do so.

```
interface if_dma();
logic [31:0] addr;
logic [31:0] data;
endinterface

module mux(clk, rst, if_dma dma_ports[n-1:0]); 

//logic

endmodule

module dma_top();

if_dma dma();

mux #(n=3)(.clk(clk), .rst(rst), dma_ports[0](rx_channel), dma_ports[1](tx_channel));

endmodule
```

Comment: Error : 'dma_ports' already declared in this scope (mux)

Comment: Instead of adding details in comments it's better to edit the question and put them there.

Comment: You need to explain what rx_channel and tx_channel are. You can't split a single port into multiple port connections, interface or no interface port

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `dma_ports[0]` and `dma_ports[1]` as separate ports. Put them together in one go: `.dma_ports({tx_channel,rx_channel})`

Your header for `mux` is odd. Not sure if you were trying are simplifying you header for `mux` or it is what you really have. If you are using non-ANSI port style, then do not specify the ranges in the port list. Range specification goes in the port definition (ex: `input clk;`, `output [7:0] out;`, `if_dma dma_ports[N];`). With ANSI port then port-list and definition are the same. Ex:

```
module mux #(parameter N=1) (input clk, rst, if_dma dma_ports[N-1:0]);
```

Do not mix ANSI and non-ANSI port styles. ANSI style is generally recommended.